# SQL Server where clause order count > 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that works but returns all students, whether they place orders or not.  I just want those with orders.  The query works fine until I add the where clause.  How can I properly write this?

```
SELECT top 100 percent s.id, s.fname as [First Name], s.lname as [Last Name], 
(select count(student_id) from orderX x where x.student_id=s.id) as [Order Count], 
(select sum(no_attendees) from orderX x where x.student_id=s.id) as [Attendees / Participants], 
(select sum(eventHours) from orderX x where x.student_id=s.id) as [Event Hours], 
oc1.text as [Occupation 1], oc2.text as [Occupation 2], 
oc3.text as [Occupation 3], s.OccupationOther, s.dateGraduated, s.organization, s.city, s.zip, s.st, s.county,
aud.text as [Preferred Audience], pts.text as [Plans to Share], mr.text as [Main Reason]
FROM  student s  
left join occupation1 oc1 on s.Occupation1 = oc1.id
left  join occupation2 oc2 on s.Occupation2 = oc2.id
left  join occupation3 oc3 on s.Occupation3 = oc3.id
left  join audience aud on s.audience = aud.id
left  join PlanToShare pts on s.PlanToShare = pts.id
left  join mainReason mr on s.mainReason = mr.id

where [Order Count] > 0
```

Comment: what a query... Are you sure there is no other way?

Comment: I know it is ugly but does the job ~!

Comment: `Where` statement doesn't recognize your column names. Use full query for count

Comment: @user2055729 - Willem is right. You can clean it up and remove the correlated subqueries. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

For starters you could replace your `where` clause by

`where (select count(student_id) from orderX x where x.student_id=s.id) > 0`

Comment: The reason I wrote "for starters" is the fact that while this solves your problem, your query should be constructed in an entirely different way. And this is why I upvote for @GurV 's answer, which I suggest you should mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I think no correlation needed here. Find all the aggregates in subquery and "inner" join it (inner because you are anyways going to filter out zero count rows)

```
select top 100 percent s.id,
    s.fname as [First Name],
    s.lname as [Last Name],
    x.order_count as [Order Count],
    x.attendess_participants as [Attendees / Participants],
    x.eventHours as [Event Hours],
    oc1.text as [Occupation 1],
    oc2.text as [Occupation 2],
    oc3.text as [Occupation 3],
    s.OccupationOther,
    s.dateGraduated,
    s.organization,
    s.city,
    s.zip,
    s.st,
    s.county,
    aud.text as [Preferred Audience],
    pts.text as [Plans to Share],
    mr.text as [Main Reason]
from student s
left join occupation1 oc1 on s.Occupation1 = oc1.id
left join occupation1 oc2 on s.Occupation2 = oc2.id
left join occupation1 oc3 on s.Occupation3 = oc3.id
left join audience aud on s.audience = aud.id
left join PlanToShare pts on s.PlanToShare = pts.id
left join mainReason mr on s.mainReason = mr.id
inner join (
    select student_id,
        count(*) as order_count,
        sum(no_attendees) as attendess_participants,
        sum(eventHours) as event_hours
    from orderX x
    group by student_id
    ) x on x.student_id = s.id;
```

Comment: Very efficient, it runs in a fraction of the time - thanks so much for sharing this!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use

```
 where (select count(student_id) from orderX x where x.student_id=s.id)
```

instead. In sql-server you cannot use aliases in where clauses.

Comment: Yeah, it seems I type too slowly! ;-) too late again :D

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a column alias ([Order count]) in the WHERE clause. Either repeat the

```
(select count(student_id) from orderX x where x.student_id=s.id)
```

in the WHERE clause as

```
WHERE (select count(student_id) from orderX x where x.student_id=s.id) > 0
```

or use a cte.